# Realm.rx.delete() and Realm.rx.add() crash with same object

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift

Use case:

I have a favorite button, when it's favorited I press it again it changes to unfavorite and removes the record. When I re-favorite it it should insert the object again but it accuses this error below

Crash with error:

```
2019-02-20 09:58:44.348244-0300 Project[3851:768454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1babecec4 0x1b9dbda40 0x101681788 0x101683208 0x100565728 0x1006aea94 0x1006aeae4 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

```swift
struct FavoriteTool {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var didLoadFavorites: (([Tool]) -> Void)?
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var didLoadFavorites: (([Tool]) -> Void)?
    func isFavorite(favoriteTool: FavoriteTool) -> Observable<Results<FavoriteTool>> {
        return favorites(filter: "id == '\(favoriteTool.id)'")
    }

    func favorite(favoriteTool: FavoriteTool) {
        Observable.just(favoriteTool)
            .subscribe(Realm.rx.add())
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func unfavorite(favoriteTool: FavoriteTool) {
        favorites(filter: "id == '\(favoriteTool.id)'")
            .subscribe(Realm.rx.delete())
            .dispose()
    }

    func favorites(filter predicateFormat: String? = nil) -> Observable<Results<FavoriteTool>> {
        guard let realm = try? Realm() else {
            return Observable.empty()
        }
        var results: Results<FavoriteTool> = realm.objects(FavoriteTool.self)
        if let predicate = predicateFormat {
            results = results.filter(predicate)
        }

        return Observable.collection(from: results)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it real code? Why do you use Observable.collection in the first place? Can you please re-format your code to at least remove duplicated lines?

Comment: yes real code? duplicate lines? I create repo on GitHub you can see?
https://github.com/micheltlutz/FavoriteRxRealm

Comment: The error is pretty clear *Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction* - which means you are modifying an already managed Realm object but you're doing it outside a write transaction. On which line does the error occur? I also don't see any Realm write code in your project. How are you attempting to store your data?

Comment: Tks for the infos. I understood the part of the transaction that was being dealt with, but RxRealm already takes care of that in a thread of it. I have the option to do it manually but the problem occurs that when I try to rewrite a record that was deleted in the case with the same id it just tries to get problems since I'm still in the same trace. I'm already working on the solution. I'll post here as soon as I finish.

Realm.rx.add() execute write transaction see [Doc RxRealm Swift](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm#write-transactions)